# how to add a cmd or bash widget in my UI C# / WebView

Tags: c#, user-interface, webview, avalonia, web-widget

I would like to add a user control of type (bash WSL) or cmd windows in my app written in c # avalonia, like in vs code.

I'm pretty sure there is a project to import a bash into a web viewer, i would like to know if anyone knows about one. if there was a web widget of this type I could import it by creating a web viewer in avalonia to start this service.